# Delete all login.keychain files

Tags: mac, script, operating-systems, xorg, keychain

Does anyone know a way to script the deletion all login.keychain files from all user directories on Mac OS X?  This is a lab environment bound to AD, and when a user changes their password, without correcting their keychain upon first login, it gets messy.  Mass deletion once a week (or logoff hook) seems easier than training students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cron job with maybe `rm -rf /Users/*/Library/Keychains` but logoff hook might work better.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What would you do with a cron job, etc...

Comment: The command I posted would remove the local keychain folder of all users. Is that what you wanted to do? All unix like systems have a cron serivce that let's you schedule commands. You can setup cron to run a command once a week or anytime really. You can view the currents logged in users cron job by doing running "crontab -l" in terminal and use sudo to view the root users cron jobs. But if you have a lot of computers this will be a pain to setup by hand.